# fft on daily temperature data i

Tags: r, fft

I have 30 years of daily temperature data and is trying to determine whether there is  cyclic behavior on this dataset. I am using R and is applying fft.( fft is new concept to me))

```
require(seas)
require(xts)
require(zoo)
require(TSA)
data(mscdata)
d1 <- (mksub(mscdata, id=1108447)) # eg of sample data format
testf <- xts(d1$t_min,d1$date) # covert data into time series class 
periodogram(d1$t_min)
```

When the plot comes out in R, I am unable discern the peaks. I am not certain how to adjust both axis so the peaks on a periodogram so it can be more visible. 
how can I plot the period rather than frequency on the axis in R? ( period = 1/frequency)

any guidance would be appreciated

Comment: You can usually use the `range` of all the collective values.  Like `ylim = range(all y values)`

Comment: The periodogram function computes its own fft data and then plot it. i am not certain how to find the range from this so i can specifically assign the y limits ..hence why i am loss

Comment: Why do you convert `d1$t_min` to a time serie class?

Comment: I tried to run it periodogram function and i keep getting errors. It was only until i change the class, then a plot was generated ..(my R knowledge is still very much in its infancy stages)

Comment: Hi, I am not sure if your question has been answered, but I just posted a similar question with a reproducible example. If you don't mind, please have a look and see if you can answer it! Thanks

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28817794/detecting-trends-in-r-periodogram-and-fft