# Detecting Seasonality in R

Tags: r, signals, time-series, signal-processing, fft

Problem: Detecting cyclical patterns in daily data using periodogram and FFT in R.

The issue is how to code in R the periodogram to detect monthly, quarterly, semi-annual, annual..etc cyclical patterns in the data. In other words I need to detect the existence of cyclical patterns for low frequencies ( ie: 1 year=> 2*pi/365, 6 months = > 4*pi/365, etc)

Reproducible Example:

```
 library(weatherData)
 w2009=getWeatherForYear("sfo",2009)
 w2010=getWeatherForYear("sfo",2010)
 w2011=getWeatherForYear("sfo",2011)
 w2012=getWeatherForYear("sfo",2012)
 w2013=getWeatherForYear("sfo",2013)
 w2014=getWeatherForYear("sfo",2014)
 w=rbind(w2009,w2010); w=rbind(w,w2011); w=rbind(w,w2012) 
 w=rbind(w,w2013); w=rbind(w,w2014)

 # Next we analyze the periodograms
 # This is IMAGE 1
 TSA::periodogram(w$Max_TemperatureF)
 # Next: I dont really know to use this information
 GeneCycle::periodogram(w$Max_TemperatureF)
 # Next THIS IS IMAGE 2
 stats::spectrum(w$Max_TemperatureF)
 # I also tried . This is IMAGE 3
 f.data <- GeneCycle::periodogram(tmax)
 harmonics <- 1:365
 plot(f.data$freq[harmonics]*length(tmax),]
      f.data$spec[harmonics]/sum(f.data$spec),
      xlab="Harmonics (Hz)", ylab="Amplitute Density", type="h")
```

[image: TSA Periodogram]

[image: Spectrum Periodogram]

[image: GeneCyle]

After reading the answers, I did:

```
 per <- TSA::periodogram(w$Max_TemperatureF,lwd = 1)
 x <- which(per$freq < 0.01)
 plot(x = per$freq[x], y = per$spec[x], type="s")
```

[image: Low Freq]

My question is what does it all mean? Do we have a seasonality cycle?

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a long periods (365 days) you will find it under very low frequency

```
> 1/365
[1] 0.002739726
```

You can actually see a peak on the left of your first image at this value. Filter to lower frequencies if you want to zoom-in:

```
per <- TSA::periodogram(w$Max_TemperatureF,lwd = 1)
x <- which(per$freq < 0.01)
plot(x = per$freq[x], y = per$spec[x], type="s")
```

Another way to search for periodicity is auto-correlation estimation (`acf`):

```
acf(w$Max_TemperatureF, lag.max = 365*3)
```

See also seasonal decomposition:

```
ts1 <- ts(data = w$Max_TemperatureF, frequency = 365)
plot( stl(ts1, s.window = "periodic"))
```

Comment: Thanks, I added the periodogram on the low frequency. However I thought that to find an annual, the frequency was 2*pi/365, why is 1/365 enough? So the frequency is where per$freq has a spike right? How do you calculate the amplitude then?  Thanks !!!

Comment: Right. If you have the frequency "suspect", you can go to seasonal decomposition: value is decomposed to periodic part (with amplitude), trend and remainder (see `stl`).

Comment: The data you have are daily time series - that is why the annual frequency is 1/365.

Comment: Last question I promise, I dont get how you use this to find cycles, because if you want 1. monthly you change x <- which(per$freq < 1/12), 2. weekly x <- which(per$freq < 1/52), 3. 2-years: x <- which(per$freq < 1/(365*2)). All the graphs look essentially the same. So how can you tell?

Comment: Changing x is just a "zoom" in presentation. The answer is in the peaks. If there is no monthly periodicity then there will be no peak at freq = 1/30.